# Passing mono audio data to AVAudioEnvironmentNode

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioengine, avaudioplayernode

I am attempting to use an `AVAudioEnvironmentNode` to produce 3D spatialized sound for a game I'm working on.  The `AVAudioEnvironmentNode` documentation states, "It is important to note that only inputs with a mono channel connection format to the environment node are spatialized. If the input is stereo, the audio is passed through without being spatialized. Currently inputs with connection formats of more than 2 channels are not supported."  I have indeed found this to be the case.  When I load audio buffers with two channels into an `AudioPlayerNode` and connect the node to an `AVAudioEnvironmentNode`, the output sound is not spatialize.  My question is, how can I send mono data to the `AVAudioEnvironmentNode`?

I've tried creating a mono `.wav` file using `Audacity` as well as loading an `AVAudioPCMBuffer` with sine wave data programmatically. I find that either way, when I create a single channel audio buffer and attempt to load the buffer into an `AudioPlayerNode`, my program crashes with the following error:

> 2016-02-17 06:36:07.695 Test Scene[1577:751557] 06:36:07.694 ERROR:
>   [0x1a1691000] AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:423: ScheduleBuffer: required
>   condition is false: _outputFormat.channelCount ==
>   buffer.format.channelCount 2016-02-17 06:36:07.698 Test
>   Scene[1577:751557] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false:
>   _outputFormat.channelCount == buffer.format.channelCount'

Checking the `AVAudioPlayerNode` output bus does indeed reveal that it expects 2 channels. It's unclear to me how this can be changed, or even if it should be.

I stipulate that I have very little experience working with `AVFoundation` or audio data in general. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you have solved this already, but for anyone else:

When connecting your AVAudioPlayerNode to an AVAudioMixerNode or any other node that it can connect to, you need to specify the number of channels there:

```
audioEngine.connect(playerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: AVAudioFormat.init(standardFormatWithSampleRate: 96000, channels: 1))
```

You can check if the sample rate is 96000 for your file in Audacity, or 'Get Info' in Finder.

Comment: I think the input to the environment node can only be one channel; if the source of your input has more channels than one, you can downsample the output of your source with an AVAudioMixerNode (similar to the way you did above). Since the AVAudioEngine mixer node is the end of the line, you cannot connect its output to an AVAudioEnvironmentNode. Rather, connect the player node to the mixer node you created, and then connect the mixer node to the environment node. The environment node then connects to the main mixer node.